# how to printf a long typed value using input size modifier?

Tags: java, string, formatting, printf, string-formatting

This is basically what I am trying to do

```
// ... some code, calculations, what have you ...
long timeToAdd = returnTimeToAddInLongFormat();

// lets output the long type now, and yes i need the width and precision.
System.out.printf("Time to add: %13.10ld", timeToAdd);
```

I've read most of the google searches around the topic and think I understand how to do it conceptually, but the JRE keeps throwing me a `UnknownFormatConversionException` and telling me my input size modifier `l` doesnt work.

Is there another way to do this, or did I miss something small?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Java treats all integer values as `d`, there is no ld. Even byte and BigInteger is a `d` type. It also assumes integers have no decimal places.  If you want to show 10 zeros, you can convert to double first and use `f`